# CodeIgniter | Unable to locate the specified class: Session.php

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, controller

I'm wondering why I always meet "**Unable to locate the specified class: Session.php**" after i click the login button.

What I'm trying to do is I have a controller for login. And after the login validate is true, I want to redirect it to another controller.

The action for login view button is in Controller_A
Controller_A

```
public function login()
        {
            $postData   = $this->input->post();
            $validate   = $this->model_Auth->validate_login($postData);
            if ($validate)
            {
                
                $newdata = array(
                    'MEMBER_ID'             => $validate[0]->MEMBER_ID,
                    'MEMBER_NAME'           => $validate[0]->MEMBER_NAME,
                    'MEMBER_CARD_NO'        => $validate[0]->MEMBER_CARD_NO,
                    'MEMBER_PLACE_OF_BIRTH' => $validate[0]->MEMBER_PLACE_OF_BIRTH,
                    'MEMBER_DATE_OF_BIRTH'  => $validate[0]->MEMBER_DATE_OF_BIRTH,
                    'MEMBER_ADDRESS'        => $validate[0]->MEMBER_ADDRESS,
                    'MEMBER_POIN'           => $validate[0]->MEMBER_POIN,
                    'MEMBER_KUPON'          => $validate[0]->MEMBER_KUPON,
                    //'password'            => $validate[0]->password,
                    'logged_in'             => TRUE,   
                );
                $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
                redirect(base_url("Controller_B"));
```

Controller_B

```
class Controller_B extends CI_Controller 
    {   
        public function __Construct() 
        {
            parent::__Construct();
            $this->load->model("model_Member");
            date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');
        }
        public function index() 
        {
            if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')) 
            {
                $this->template->load('templates/layout', 'content', 'member/info');
            }
            else 
            {
                $data = array('alert' => false);
                $this->load->view('home/login', $data);
            }
        }
```

I tried this code for Contoller_B as well

```
class Controller_B extends Controller_A 
    {   
        public function __Construct() 
        {
            parent::__Construct();
            include(APPPATH.'controllers/Home.php');
            $this->load->model("model_Member");
            date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');
        }
        public function index() 
        {
            if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')) 
            {
                $this->template->load('templates/layout', 'content', 'member/info');
            }
            else 
            {
                $data = array('alert' => false);
                $this->load->view('home/login', $data);
            }
        }
```

But neither of them works. It still show the "**Unable to locate the specified class: Session.php**" error. As for the autoload.php, I already add the session library.

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session', 'template');
```

As for the Session.php. I have it in

> system/libraries/Session/Session.php

Can anyone help me in this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Could be missing, check for system/libraries/Session.php

Comment: I'd install a fresh copy of Codeigniter, then copy your view/controller/model  files there and check if the error still exists

Comment: @Vickel I do your suggestion and the error still there. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: you could use the native php session with superglobal $_SESSION: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php. It is not possible (at least for me) to see why your code snippet would not be able to locate the CI Session class. A last hint, it looks like you are using CI 3.x, upgrade to the very latest version CI 3.1.11

Comment: at first, check whether you are going inside the if($validate) scope?? If yes then check are you getting data in $newdata .